# Div won't stack

Tags: html, css

So I have read about divs being stacked and many posts suggest using clear: left; but when I do that it "clears left" so doesnt work.

When I placed the divs in and the current css styles I am left with the legal div sitting next to the map div and the same with the copyright/design divs opposed to those two sets ONLY stacking.

### HTML CODE

```
<div id="footer">
<div id="footerLeft"></div>
<div id="footerMap"></div>
<div id="footerLegal"></div>
<div id="footerLinkedin"></div>
<div id="footerLeftPadding"></div>
<div id="footerFacebook"></div>
<div id="footerRightPadding"></div>
<div id="footerTwitter"></div>
<div id="footerCopyright"></div>
<div id="footerDesign"></div>
<div id="footerRight"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS CODE

```
#footer {
float:left;
height: 50px;
width: 1200px;
}
#footerLeft{
float:left;
height: 50px;
width: 90px;
}
#footerMap{
float:left;
height: 25px;
width: 366px;
}
#footerLegal{
float:left;
height: 25px;
width: 366px;
}
#footerLinkedin{
float:left;
height: 50px;
width: 48px;
background-image:url(images/footer/web_page_footer_03.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#footerLeftPadding{
float:left;
height: 50px;
width: 22px;
}
#footerFacebook{
float:left;
height: 50px;
width: 48px;
background-image:url(images/footer/web_page_footer_05.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#footerRightPadding{
float:left;
height: 50px;
width: 22px;
}
#footerTwitter{
float:left;
height: 50px;
width: 48px;
background-image:url(images/footer/web_page_footer_07.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#footerCopyright{
float:left;
height: 25px;
width: 366px;
background-image:url(images/footer/web_page_footer_08.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#footerDesign{
float:left;
height: 25px;
width: 366px;
background-image:url(images/footer/web_page_footer_10.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#footerRight{
float:left;
height: 50px;
width: 90px;
background-image:url(images/footer/web_page_footer_09.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so users can better understand and visualize the problem.

Comment: A question can't be clear when there is no question.

Comment: Well, you make `#footer` 1200px wide, but all your sub-divs total up to 1800+px.  so yeah, they're going to "wrap".

Comment: try overflow: hidden and making height of footer 51px

Comment: Please tell us your desired result.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bDtyj/

Comment: Desired result is http://postimg.org/image/wlxlpctqh/